# Minimal quantum OR circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

The quantum OR circuit between $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$ can be made out of 1 Toffoli and 2 CNOT gates, 1 ancillary qubit. Is there any other implementation? Or is this the minimal in the sense of gates used?

Comment: How is this conceptually different than "the classical NAND gate can be made out of an AND gate and a NOR gate", or "the classical XOR gate can be made out of 4 NAND gates?"  What gates are you allowing as primitives?  CSWAP (Fredkin?)

Answer (score 3):

Note that there are many ways to make `or` into a reversible operation.

The truth table for the OR reads:
$$\begin{array}{ccc} x & y & x\operatorname{or}y \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}$$
so we only need to add an ancillary degree of freedom that registers the difference between the last three cases.
In other words, if $f(x,y)=x+y+xy$ is the OR operation ($+$ denotes modulo-$2$ sum here), our reversible operation must be some $g(x,y)$ such that
\begin{align}
g(0,0)&=(0,\alpha),\\
g(0,1)&=(1,\beta_1), \\
g(1,0)&=(1,\beta_2), \\
g(1,1)&=(1,\beta_3),
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ can be anything, and the $\beta_i$ have to be different from each other. Any such $g$ is reversible, and can therefore be implemented as a quantum gate.

To satisfy the above constraints, we clearly need at least two ancillary bits, and then any assignment to the $\beta_i$ works. For example, we can choose $\beta_0=00, \beta_1=01, \beta_2=10$.

The above argument tells you that you cannot implement a quantum OR operation with less than three qubits. As to how many "elementary gates" you need to realise such an operation as a circuit, that question is meaningless without a choice of the elementary gate set to use.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not localized to **quantum gates,** but can be rephrased as "how do I implement a (classical) **reversible gate** that can realize a logical $\mathsf{OR}$?"

I propose a $3$-input "upstart" gate acting on $\{0,1\}^3$ and producing $3$ outputs as follows:

```
C X Y || O X Y
==============
0 0 0 || 0 0 0
0 0 1 || 1 0 1
0 1 0 || 1 1 0
0 1 1 || 1 1 1
1 0 0 || 1 0 0
1 0 1 || 0 0 1
1 1 0 || 0 1 0
1 1 1 || 0 1 1
```

Here we see that the first bit is evaluated to the $\mathsf{OR}$ of the second and third bits when the first bit is $0$, and is evaluated to the $\mathsf{NOR}$ of the second and third bits when the first bit is $1$.

This can be written in matrix form as:

$$\mathsf{UPSTART}=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This of course can be written in many other ways.

Comment: There appears to have been a small typo in your matrix - I believe I've fixed it, but it might be worth double checking